# Ubuntu 16.04 graphics failure: (EE) error, (NI) not implemented; (EE) VESA(0): V_BIOS address 0x0 out of range

Tags: 16.04, graphics, xorg

Both normal and failsafeX modes not starting in Ubuntu 16.04. Here is my log file:

```
[    34.184] 
X.Org X Server 1.18.3
Release Date: 2016-04-04
[    34.187] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    34.187] Build Operating System: Linux 3.13.0-92-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    34.188] Current Operating System: Linux Sinha 4.4.0-53-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64
[    34.188] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=8a6b11de-3582-4e10-b96c-2bdd22a77676 ro recovery nomodeset
[    34.190] Build Date: 22 July 2016  07:50:34AM
[    34.191] xorg-server 2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2.3 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    34.192] Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
[    34.194]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    34.194] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    34.198] (++) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.failsafe.log", Time: Thu Dec 15 13:32:41 2016
[    34.199] (++) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe"
[    34.200] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    34.200] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    34.200] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen" (0)
[    34.200] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Configured Monitor"
[    34.201] (**) |   |-->Device "Configured Video Device"
[    34.201] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    34.201] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    34.201] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    34.201] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    34.201] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    34.201]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    34.201] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    34.201]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    34.201] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    34.201]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    34.201] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    34.201]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    34.201] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    34.201]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    34.201] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    34.201] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    34.201] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    34.201] (II) Loader magic: 0x560c4d834da0
[    34.201] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    34.201]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    34.201]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[    34.201]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[    34.201]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[    34.201] (EE) dbus-core: error connecting to system bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.FileNotFound (Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory)
[    34.201] (--) using VT number 2

[    34.201] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    34.202] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:0fe4:17aa:3802 rev 161, Mem @ 0xc2000000/16777216, 0xb0000000/268435456, 0xc0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00003000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    34.203] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    34.254] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    34.379] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.379]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    34.379]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
[    34.379] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    34.379] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    34.379] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    34.379] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.379]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 2.3.4
[    34.379]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    34.379]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    34.379] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    34.382] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[    34.382] (II) Loading sub module "vbe"
[    34.382] (II) LoadModule: "vbe"
[    34.383] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
[    34.394] (II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.394]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.1.0
[    34.394]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    34.394] (II) Loading sub module "int10"
[    34.394] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
[    34.394] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[    34.409] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.409]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    34.409]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    34.409] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[    34.409] (EE) VESA(0): V_BIOS address 0x0 out of range
[    34.409] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    34.409] (II) UnloadSubModule: "int10"
[    34.409] (II) Unloading int10
[    34.409] (II) UnloadSubModule: "vbe"
[    34.409] (II) Unloading vbe
[    34.409] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[    34.409] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    34.409] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    34.409] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    34.409] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.failsafe.log" for additional information.
[    34.409] (EE) 
[    34.416] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

xorg.conf.failsafe

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "vesa"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A complete reinstall worked:

Uninstall

```
sudo apt-get purge xorg "xserver-*"
sudo apt-get purge lightdm plymouth
sudo rm -rf /etc/X11/xorg
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Install

```
sudo apt-get install xauth xorg openbox lightdm plymouth
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

[Refer this for more](https://www.computersnyou.com/4945/re-install-xorg-xserver-completely-ubuntu/)

Comment: Oh boy, after trying so many things for hours this finally worked. You should accept it as the answer.

Comment: This solved a separate issue for me. I would get to login screen and have no mouse or keyboard ability. It took me three days of trying many many things, the solution was to boot to grub, edit boot options adding a 3 as the final argument to linux to boot with no graphics, and then run the above commands.

Comment: didn't work. still shows the "running in low graphics mode"... :(

Comment: Thanks. This _finally_ solved some weird issues I was having after installing Nvidia drivers.