# Unistalled Xorg, now I cannot login

Tags: xorg, recovery-mode

I was getting the following error

Ubuntu 16.04 graphics failure: (EE) error, (NI) not implemented; (EE) VESA(0): V_BIOS address 0x0 out of range

After following the uninstall part of the solution in this answer [Ubuntu 16.04 graphics failure: (EE) error, (NI) not implemented; (EE) VESA(0): V_BIOS address 0x0 out of range](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860841/ubuntu-16-04-graphics-failure-ee-error-ni-not-implemented-ee-vesa0-v) , I can not boot even using recovery mode because I get Target filesystem doesnt have requested /sbin/init. How could I install the needed packages?

Comment: You might be at the point of reinstalling. Is that an option?

Comment: No, because the live CD doesnt allow me to reinstal without losing /home files

Comment: Check this out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/269880/re-install-ubuntu-without-losing-data-in-home-folder

Comment: I saw that post, but unfortunately, I can not select that first option un the live CD. The only options that I am allowed to select imply to lose the /home data

Comment: You must only have (1) partition then.

Comment: No. Root, home and swap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97859/discussion-between-ajgringo619-and-william).

Answer (score 0):

You should at least be able to fall back into a shell with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, or perhaps with a `grub` command (you'd have to google that). If you can't, this might not be worth pursuing.

I think that what you would have to do is to use a live-USB to `chroot` into the system, then start repairing the system.

For information on how to use `chroot` I would look at the [Arch-Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chroot#Usage).

If you do get into a shell and you simply need to rectify having removed [Xorg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg), you would have to reinstall that, obviously, and I'm not sure if you would also have to reinstall [GDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM) and [Gnome3](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME).

Those links will walk through how to install it all, but in all honesty, having been through this stuff before, it's almost always quicker to just wipe and reinstall. I know that sounds drastic, but it takes like 20 minutes of zero effort to reinstall, particularly with a fast internet connection.

I personally try to have my partitions set up so that I can reinstall at the drop of a hat with no data loss, because I simply don't have the time to try and fix my OS, which usually seems like it will take 5 minutes but takes 5 hours :/ .

Comment: Indeed, if I delete single option from the 'linux' line I can get a shell. But I need a internet wire because I can not install the packages that I uninstalled without It, since I can not connect to wifi from that shell without a GUI( maybe I could, I have not really checked It). Tomorrow in the morning I will try to install those packages

Comment: @william you should be able to connect to wifi through the shell, check out [NetworkManager on ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Usage)